# How to bind data to a user control using template selector

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm using template selector for data grid in WPF.

I've got this code:

```
    <l:ProblemTemplateSelector x:Key="problemTemplateSelector">
        <l:ProblemTemplateSelector.ArithmeticTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="LightBlue">
                    <l:ArithmeticUserControl Problem="{Binding ElementName=this}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </l:ProblemTemplateSelector.ArithmeticTemplate>
    </l:ProblemTemplateSelector>
```

In the usercontrol, I need to set in Problem property all the element, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

UPDATE 1:

I'm gonna be more specific if you need details, I've got a class Exercise where is a user control:

```
public class Exercise : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProblemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Problem", typeof(Problem), typeof(Exercise), new PropertyMetadata(null, ));

    public virtual Problem Problem
    {
        get
        {
            return (Problem)GetValue(ProblemProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ProblemProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

This I've got another class where is derived from Exercise.

```
public partial class ArithmeticUserControl : Exercise
{
    public ArithmeticUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public override Problem Problem
    {
        get 
        { 
             return base.Problem;
        }
          set 
        { 
            base.Problem = value;

            Arithmetic p = (Arithmetic)value;
            Number1 = p.Number1;
            Number2 = p.Number2;
            Operator = p.Operation;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Try out ="{Binding TemplatedParent}", Am I right that "All the element" is an element which is templated?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work

Comment: Ok, could you elaborate what you mean when saying "all the element", the Control itself or data item which is bound to ListBoxItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to declare the binding as `"{Binding}"` and have it bind the `Problem` property to the data item.

**EDIT:** After seeing your example, you need to change how you're handling the `Problem` property. The WPF binding system does not make use of CLR properties, so the CLR properties exist *only* as a convenience for user code. Because of this, the code in your property is never being executed when the value is set through binding.

Instead, you need to handle property value changes by overriding `OnPropertyChanged`. For example, in your inherited class:

```
protected override OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Property == ProblemProperty)
    {
        Arithmetic p = (Arithmetic)Problem;
        Number1 = p.Number1;
        Number2 = p.Number2;
        Operator = p.Operation;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Oscar: How are you determining that it isn't working? Are you getting binding errors in the output window? Are you monitoring `OnPropertyChanged` and it never gets called for `Problem`?

Comment: I'm only putting breakpoints in the property.. so, do you think I need to use OnPropertyChanged?

Comment: @oscar.imbres: The wrapper is not used by the binding system, you need to register a property changed callback in the `Register` method (use an overload with MetaData and specify a callback within the MetaData) if you want to monitor those changes.

Comment: How would it be that overload?

Comment: @oscar: You will either have to override `OnPropertyChanged` or attach a handler to the dependency property itself (the former is the easier and more straightforward option, IMO) to detect changes. Your C# property is there only for convenience and is not used by the binding system, which is why it's important that you *only* use `GetValue` and `SetValue` in it.

Comment: Oh man, you did it! Thanks a million!  It only left this line: base.OnPropertyChanged(e); and it's binding the data

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a `{Binding}` to pass a Data Item in the control.
If this won't help, along with your control add a TextBlock and see what is binds through straight binding:

```
<Grid Background="LightBlue">                     
   <l:ArithmeticUserControl Problem="{Binding ElementName=this}" />                 
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Background="Green" ></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

So on green background you shoudl see what is came to the ListBoxItem

Comment: It says the type name. I cannot understand why Problem property is not assigned

Comment: do you think I need to do some with MetaData?